# How to store embedded struct with GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go

How can I store an embedded struct with GORM if I have a type like this

```
type A struct {
    point GeoPoint
}

type GeoPoint struct {
    Lat float64
    Lon float64
}
```

GORM tries to add it in a new table, but I want to add it  as another field.

How can this be done?

Comment: Export the `point` field by making it upper case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone, who's searching the way to put struct inside GORM model and make it marshalling and unmarshalling automatically.

This solution is based on **chris**'s answer. And it works!

For example, I want to put array of Childrens inside Parent as marshalled JSON:

```
type Child struct {
    Lat float64
    Lng float64
}

type ChildArray []Children

func (sla *ChildArray) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(src.([]byte), &sla)
}

func (sla ChildArray) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    val, err := json.Marshal(sla)
    return string(val), err
}

type Parent struct {
    *gorm.Model    
    Childrens ChildArray `gorm:"column:childrens;type:longtext"`
}
```

Comment: For `Scan` I had to use `return json.Unmarshal([]byte(src.(string)), &sla)`, otherwise it worked! Genius

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
   type A struct {
    point GeoPoint `gorm:"embedded"`
}
```

Comment: This will add 2 separate columns instead of saving `GeoPoint` as json in the database!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Gorm, but with **sqlx** you will need to implement the sql.Scanner and sql.Valuer interfaces to allow the data to be converted to the postgres `point` type. The code below isn't checking for errors so it will need some tweaks.

https://play.golang.org/p/2-Y-wSeAWnj

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type GeoPoint struct {
    Lat float64
    Lon float64
}

func (gp GeoPoint) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("(%d,%d)", gp.Lat, gp.Lon), nil
}

func (gp GeoPoint) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    raw := src.(string)
    coords := raw[1 : len(raw)-1]
    vals := strings.Split(coords, ",")
    gp.Lat, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(vals[0], 64)
    gp.Lon, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(vals[1], 64)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    gp := GeoPoint{Lat: 112, Lon: 53}
    d, _ := gp.Value()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d)

    gp.Scan("(53, -110)")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", gp)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, using gorm you never define fields with the first letter in lower case.

If you make sure GeoPoint is linked as Aid , you can use ForeingKey tag like,
MAKE SURE Id is table A 's primary key.

```golang
type A struct {
    Id int `gorm:"column:"id""`
    Point GeoPoint `gorm:"column:geo_point;ForeignKey:OrderId"`
}

type GeoPoint struct {
    Aid int
    Lat float64
    Lon float64
}

func main(){
    ...
    ...
    var as []A
    if e:=db.Model(&A{}).Find(&as).Error;e!=nil{
        handle(e)
    }
    fmt.Println(as)
}
```

If not linked by primary key. You can use middleware like

```golang
type A struct {
    Id int `gorm:"column:"id""`
    Point GeoPoint `gorm:"column:geo_point"`
}

func (a *A) AfterFind()error{
   return db.Model(&GeoPoint{}).First(&(a.Point)).Error
}

type GeoPoint struct {
    Aid int
    Lat float64
    Lon float64
}

func main(){
    ...
    ...
    var as []A
    if e:=db.Model(&A{}).Find(&as).Error;e!=nil{
        handle(e)
    }
    fmt.Println(as)
}
```