# How to save array of structs

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to save an Array of Structs.
I tried:

```
type ShiftValue struct {
    Hour   uint8 `json:"hour"`
    Minute uint8 `json:"minute"`
}

type Shift struct {
    Start ShiftValue `json:"start"`
    End   ShiftValue `json:"end"`
}

type Config struct {
    ID                        uuid.UUID       `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;index;" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt                 time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt                 time.Time       `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt                 *time.Time      `json:"deleted_at,omitempty"`
    Shifts                    []Shift         `gorm:"type:varchar(100)[];" json:"shifts,"`
}
```

But is not working. I also tried to save Shifts as `pq.StringArray`:

```
type Config struct {
    ID                        uuid.UUID       `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;index;" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt                 time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt                 time.Time       `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt                 *time.Time      `json:"deleted_at,omitempty"`
    Shifts                    pq.StringArray  `gorm:"type:varchar(100)[];" json:"shifts,"`
}
```

Which is kind of working, but I don't know how can I convert a slice of `Shift` to `StringArray`.
Should I use `GenericArrray`?
How can I make the conversion from `Slice` to `GenericArray` or `StringArray`?

When I `Unmarshall` the data, I do it in the following struct, I validate the data, and after that I want to save it to Database:

```
type ConfigUpdate struct {
    Shifts                    []Shift         `json:"shifts,"`
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest scenario that can be seen in gorm [embedded struct test](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/embedded_struct_test.go) is

```
package gorm_test

import "testing"

type BasePost struct {
    Id    int64
    Title string
    URL   string
}

type Author struct {
    ID    string
    Name  string
    Email string
}

type HNPost struct {
    BasePost
    Author  `gorm:"embedded_prefix:user_"` // Embedded struct
    Upvotes int32
}

type EngadgetPost struct {
    BasePost BasePost `gorm:"embedded"`
    Author   Author   `gorm:"embedded;embedded_prefix:author_"` // Embedded struct
    ImageUrl string
}
```

As can be seen, all of these Base Struct have `Id` to be referred to as `foreign` key in parent struct.

One more scenario that can be found handled in one of StackOverflow [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503001/how-to-store-embedded-struct-with-gorm).

```
type Children struct {
    Lat float64
    Lng float64
}

type ChildArray []Children

func (sla *ChildArray) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(src.([]byte), &sla)
}

func (sla ChildArray) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    val, err := json.Marshal(sla)
    return string(val), err
}

type Parent struct {
    *gorm.Model    
    Childrens ChildArray `gorm:"column:childrens;type:longtext"`
}
```

Please verify it on your own as I don't have a gorm set up. I just did the R & D part. I hope, it will help many of us. thanks